# Can both bitwise set/resets be achieved in one line with ternary operators?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I would like to express the following in a more condensed form:

```
if (a||b) { alarm |= (1UL << 4) }
else { alarm &= ~(1UL << 4) }
```

However, I am not sure how to do this given the differing bitwise assignments and not just expressions/values. i.e.:

```
alarm = (a || b) ? (|= (1UL << 4)) : (&= ~(1UL << 4));
```

Is it possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Why?  What do you gain by cramming all that logic into one line?

Comment: an end to inquiry? :)

Comment: `(a || b) ? (alarm |= (1UL << 4)) : (alarm &= ~(1UL << 4));`?

Comment: You're merely toggling a bit. If the code isn't meant for the IOCCC, the only thing you're doing is making the code harder to understand - including **you** when you look at it again two years from now. There aren't many legitimate reasons to obfuscate code in a professional setting. What I've told programmers working for me: "If you make it harder for us to figure out what you're doing, I'll take that as an admission on your part that you don't feel you're good enough to keep your job on technical skill alone and need something more. And if you don't think so, neither will I."

Comment: What does "an end to inquiry?" mean?

Comment: `alarm = (a || b) ? set_bit(alarm, 4) : clr_bit(alarm, 4);` I would prefer it to be in multiple lines with if/else, but this is the best one-liner I could get using the ternary operator ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think this would work. I wouldn't say it is more readable and it is certainly not going to result in more efficiency:

```
alarm = (alarm &~ (1UL << 4)) + ((a||b) << 4);
```

Comment: Are you sure that no brackets are missing? As far as I know `a&b+c` means: `a&(b+c)`, not `(a&b)+c`.

Comment: I, too, think that would produce the same result in `alarm` as the OP's `if` / `else` statement does.  And in one line, as requested, but of course not with use of the ternary operator.  I've no idea whether that last criterion is actually important to the OP.

Comment: Note that you are forced to write "I think this will work". That's not really acceptable for production code.  And 18 months later, when tasked to update the code, the first response of any programmer seeing that will be, "Who's the !(*&%!*&@ idiot who was trying to show off how "clever" he is?!?!"

Comment: @Andrew: No argument from me. I wouldn't write that in production code. (I wouldn't even write `(1UL << 4)` in production code.) The reason I wrote "I think this will work" is that the only guide to what's intended is some code, which might or might not reflect the actual intent of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

> Can both bitwise set/resets be achieved in one line with ternary operators?

Yes, but it's not a very satisfying reduction:

```
alarm = (a || b) ? (alarm | (1UL << 4)) : (alarm & ~(1UL << 4));
```

You cannot avoid repeating `alarm` in the second and third operands of `?:`, because each of those needs to be a complete expression that, when selected, evaluates to the wanted final value.  The original value of `alarm` is an essential input to the computation of its new value either way, so it must appear in both of the last two operands if overall you use a ternary expression.

I find the `if`-statement version clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to focus on the following part of the question:

> ```
> alarm = (a || b) ? (|= (1UL << 4)) : (&= ~(1UL << 4));
> ```
>
> Is it possible?

This is basically the same as replacing:

```
x = z ? (c + d) : (c * d);
```

By:

```
x = c (z ? + : *) d;
```

This syntax is **not** possible in C.

> I would like to express the following in a more condensed form

There are other possibilities to do this. The other answers contain examples how you can do that.

Comment: @rici I just want to tell the author of the question that your answer contains a possibility to "condense" the expression. My answer is only focusing on a certain aspect of the question: If a certain syntax is allowed by C. I'm not focusing on the aspect if it is possible to "condense" the expression in general.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The second snippet (`x = z ? (c + d)`...) should be valid code. The first one (`(z ? + : *) `) is not valid but it is equivalent to the expression in the question: The operands of the ternary operator are not "complete" expressions in both cases ...

Comment: I understood the scare quotes around "condense". It was the scare quotes around my name that I objected to.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended, but how about, pretending everything is an int and writing m for the bit(s) you want to set clear:

```
int f = -!(a||b);
  alarm = f ^ ( (f^alarm) | m);
```

The explanation is:
since (a||b) is 0 or 1, f is 0 (if either a or b is true) and -1 otherwise. In the first case the second statement is the same as

```
alarm = alarm | m
```

In the second case it is the same as

```
alarm = ~((~alarm)|m)
```

ie

```
alarm = alarm & ~m
```

I expect that some -- perhaps quite a lot of --  casting can make this work for the case you have where m and alarm are, I'd guess, unsigned longs.

But if I saw code like this I would spend a while figuring out what it did, curse the author, and change the code to the if else form

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
alarm = (alarm & ~(1UL << 4)) | ((a || b) ? (1UL << 4) : 0);
```

This always clears the bit from `alarm`, then ORs it back in if `(a || b)` is true.

It seems kinda pointless.